# Quitar heder del String de DataRecived TCP Socket

Tags: c#, tcp

Estoy conectándome a un dispositivo el cual me devuelve el siguiente Byte[] el cual al convertirlo a string se ve como lo siguiente.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.21.120.11:8003
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 109
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<stream id="13572">
  <monitor>
    <status>OK</status>
  </monitor>
</stream>
```

Mi problema es que necesito separar la cabecera y el Xml para luego procesarlos, actualmente no se si el Header puede aumentar, por ello, estoy buscando la mejor manera de realizarlo.

¿Existe una manera de transformar el string completo y así cargarlo a un XML document?

Comment: Aclara cual es tu cabecera en el string y dd es que terminaria esta cabecera